# Does Python's DataReader count as an API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance

I've been using `pandas.io.data.DataReader` to pull data from Yahoo Finance. Does this count as using an API? My somewhat rudimentary understanding of an API is that it allows you to accomplish your goal within your program (Python, Excel, etc.) without having to visit the actual website. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/usage_info_limits.html

If you access yahoo with one of the following addresses it counts as using an API:

```
/v1/public/*
/v1/yql/*
```